# Get ListItem position in custom SimpleLayout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout, android-adapter

I have a custom `ListView` with a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`. I also have a custom `SimpleAdapter` in which I override the `getView()` method and am able to retrieve clicks on the `TextView` and `CheckBox` changes. My problem is that I don't know how to get the correct clicked `ListItem` or `CheckBox` inside the `OnCheckedChanged` or `OnClick`.

**UPDATE** added whole `CustomAdapter` class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> mItems = null;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mPosicion;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        ViewHolder holder;
        mPosicion = position;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.chkbxEstado = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbxCompletado);
            holder.txtTextoAgenda = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTextoLista);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTextoAgenda.setText(mItems.get(position).get("descripcion"));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Posicion",""+mPosicion);//I don't know how to retrieve clicked position
            }
        });

        holder.chkbxEstado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("Posicion",""+mPosicion);//Or checked
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTextoAgenda;
        CheckBox chkbxEstado;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have the parameter position, what else do you need?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain correctly. The position parameter always returns a certain position, but doesn't update if I click different rows or checkboxes.

Comment: That's weird, could you post the entire adapter?

Comment: Updated with the `CustomAdapter`.

Comment: Still it is unclear what you mean by clicked position? there can just be a position that gives the position of your listitem,what else 'position' are you talking about?

Comment: Inside the onClick event, for example. When a List item is clicked, the Log shows one same position every time. It doesn't change for every different clicked item in the list. As if position remains with the same value for the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. If anybody knows a better one, please let me know. Working `CustomAdapter` class:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private List<HashMap<String, String>> mItems = null;
        private Context mContext;

        private OnClickListener mClick;
        private OnCheckedChangeListener mChecked;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, items, resource, from, to);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mItems = items;
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.chkbxEstado = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbxCompletado);
                holder.txtTextoAgenda = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTextoLista);
                holder.posicion = position; //Add the new position into the holder for each row.

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                mClick = new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(v); //Get the ViewHolder for the clicked row.
                        Log.i("Posicion",""+v.posicion);
                    }
                };

                mChecked = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(buttonView); //Get the ViewHolder for the clicked CheckBox
                        Log.i("Posicion",""+viewHolder.posicion);
                    }
                };

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtTextoAgenda.setText(mItems.get(position).get("descripcion"));

            convertView.setOnClickListener(mClick);

            holder.chkbxEstado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mChecked);

            return convertView;

        }

        public ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v){ //This method returns the ViewHolder stored in the tag if available, if not it recursively checks the parent's tag.
            if(v.getTag() == null){
                return getViewHolder((View)v.getParent());
            }
            return (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTextoAgenda;
            CheckBox chkbxEstado;
            int posicion; //Added position attribute to ViewHolder class.
        }
    }
```

Edited to re-use onClickListener() and onCheckedChangedListener() instances.

Comment: you should consider re-using instances of OnClickListener and OnCheckedChangeListener. Every time you scroll and your view gets repainted you will allocate new ones.

Comment: Nice solution!  I was hoping for something more elegant, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's solution works.  But if you are extending a CursorAdapter, the position parameter does not exist in newView() and bindView().  What to do?

They do supply a Cursor.  Use cursor.getPosition().  It does the same thing.